# Get the total of a Project from related project items in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-model

In CakePHP i've a model Project and a model ProjectRecord:

```
<?php
class Project extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'project';

    public $hasOne = array( 
        'Customer' => array( 
                'foreignKey' => false, 
                'conditions' => array('Project.customer_id = Customer.id') 
        )
    ); 

    public $hasMany = array(
        'ProjectRecord' => array(
            'className' => 'ProjectRecord',
        )
    );
}
?>
```

Model ProjectRecord:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class ProjectRecord extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'project_record';

    public $hasOne = 'Project';

}
?>
```

ProjectRecord holds the values: "amount", "costs" and "vat" (in percent)

In my projects index I want to see the total of a Project. So I've to collect all ProjectRecord that are connected with one Project, then multiply the amount with costs and vat, and then count all those numbers for one value.

I know it has something to do with virtual fields, but I can't get it right to retrieve those ProjectRecords.

I've tried to add a Helper, but no matter what I did, I got the warning that the table (Project) couldn't get loaded.

Comment: please add what you have tried

Comment: Added what I tried to do (but failed miserably..). I've deleted that part of code when trying other things.. Sorry for that! In my previous question I've founded that it has to be with virtual fields, but I can't get it to work to get related ProjectRecords.

Answer (score 1):

I would not calculate this value each time I access a product record. I think the better solution would be to calculate the values in the ProjectRecord::afterSave() callback and save the sum to the associated Project (add a field like total_sum or whatever you prefer) of the ProjectRecord that was just saved. This way you avoid additional complexity or additional queries.

Comment: And how should I combine all those record totals for a project total?

Comment: By using simple math?